# How can I remove a <none> tag without deleting the docker image itself?

Tags: docker, tags, rmi

Every time I pull an image, there are two tags pulled. Like this:

```
centos  6       f07f6ca555a5  4 weeks ago  194.6 MB  
centos  <none>  f07f6ca555a5  4 weeks ago  194.6 MB
```

How can I remove the later  tag only?

```
$ docker info
Containers: 2
 Running: 0
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 2
Images: 13
Server Version: 1.12.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 181
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge overlay host null
Kernel Version: 4.4.17-boot2docker
Operating System: Boot2Docker 1.12.1 (TCL 7.2); HEAD : ef7d0b4 - Thu Aug 18 21:18:06 UTC 2016
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 7.604 GiB
Name: default
ID: WUS6:YHEN:O4U4:6GYZ:ECIX:5KQA:SAYJ:HNPY:RJB4:AEMR:QQCE:777M
Docker Root Dir: /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker
Debug mode (client): false
Debug mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 14
 Goroutines: 23
 System Time: 2016-10-10T02:13:57.107136165Z
 EventsListeners: 0
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
 provider=virtualbox
```

docker rmi $(docker images --filter "dangling=true" -q --no-trunc)
This command is not working for me. Actually they are the same image.

Comment: This is strange, I've never seen <none> tag! Would you please paste `docker info`

Comment: Added in the revised question.

Comment: @JohnnyWang I have rewritten my answer: there was a bug supposedly fixed about empty tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a 1.11.2 bug, reported in [issue 23895](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/23895) and [issue 23503](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/23503#issuecomment-225951609).
It is supposed to be fixed in 1.12.x, with [PR 23549](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/23549): "**Do not show empty tags for digest references in output**".

> When a repository has a tag and digests, show tag for each digest value.
>   **Rows will not be duplicated for the same image name which has both a tag and a digest**.

If you still see this in 1.12.1, you should open a new issue, as it might be a regression from 1.12.0.

Comment: It's not related, it's not orphaned image, strangely it's a valid image with <none> tag!

Comment: @Boynux good point. I have completed the answer accordingly. As I mention (in this revised answer), note that you can commit an image without specifying the repo and the tag, only its image name: that would give you a `xxx:<none>` image.

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue with devicemapper or a bug in docker itself. it's normal to see `<none>:<none>` but it your case it's only `centos:<none>` tag!

I suggest to remove the centos image altogether and pull it again, if the problem persists please file an issue in docker project.

to remove the image simply run `docker rmi f07f6ca555a5`.

It's also helpful to provide `docker info` output.